# Jenkins JCasC extra slash in repository name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Not sure if this is really a bug or did I miss configured something, but it seems that via jcasc plugin it adds one extra slash on repository name after `https://github.com/` like bellow:

[image]

My configuration is:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('Automation-CI') {
description('Job generated by DSL')
branchSources {
    github {
        id('Automation-CI')
        scanCredentialsId('token')
        repository('myproject/automation')
        includes('*')
        buildForkPRHead(false)
        buildForkPRMerge(false)
        buildOriginBranch(true)
        buildOriginBranchWithPR(true)
        buildOriginPRHead(true)
        buildOriginPRMerge(true)
    }
}
orphanedItemStrategy {
    discardOldItems {
        daysToKeep(5)
        numToKeep(3)
    }
}
```

}

My environment:

```
Jenkins version: 2.295
github-branch-source: 2.11.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For the one that got the same error, to resolve it switch to:

```
        repoOwner('myproject')
        repository('automation')
```